# RSSTail alternative with OPML support?

Tags: bash, rss, opml

`rsstail` can't handle OPML list, but can only track single RSS feed, AFAIK

Is there any CLI alternative (`tail` like) that can do this task?

Or online service that can transform OPML to valid single URL RSS, which I can then pipe to rsstail?

Answer (score 2):

[image: note]
**Here a clean solution, the [`OPML`](http://opml.org/spec2.opml) file can have multiple feeds**.

From the spec of `OPML` linked above:

> Subscription lists
> A subscription list is a possibly multiple-level list of subscriptions to feeds. Each sub-element of the body of the OPML document is a node of type rss or an outline element that contains nodes of type rss.

##### Using [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
xidel -e '//outline[@xmlUrl and @type="rss"]/join(("-u", @xmlUrl))' -s file.opml |
    xargs rsstail
```

The file can be remote, using `http` or `https`:

```
xidel --input-format xml \
    -e '//outline[@xmlUrl and @type="rss"]/join(("-u", @xmlUrl))' \
    -s http://hosting.opml.org/dave/spec/subscriptionList.opml |
    xargs rsstail
```

##### If you need only the first match

```
xidel -e '(//outline[@xmlUrl and @type="rss"]/join(("-u", @xmlUrl)))[1]' \
    -s file.opml | xargs rsstail
```

##### To go further, you can join multiple sources, like:

```
{ 
    echo ' -u https://stackoverflow.com/feeds '
    xidel ..... file.opml
} | xargs rsstail
```

`xidel`: https://github.com/benibela/xidel
`xidel` download: https://sourceforge.net/projects/videlibri/files/Xidel/Xidel%20development/

---

**If you are using [windows](/questions/tagged/windows), to prevent quotes issues, run this code as [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**.

Comment: Does it display the latest item from all feeds?

Comment: I think so, `xidel` is just a tool to fetch `rss` feeds (in this case), it don't change `rsstail` behavior. You should give a try. If you found an issue, tell me

Answer (score 0):

`cat opml.xml | grep xmlUrl | sed 's/.*xmlUrl="/-u /;s/".*//' | xargs rsstail`